# Resistor bridging diagonal of square circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors

Consider a square ABCD where there is a one-ohm resistor on each side of the square. If there is also a one-ohm resistor bridging the AC diagonal, what is the equivalent resistance in ohms between points A and C? [image]

Comment: please show your work

Comment: do you see any way to simplify the circuit?

Comment: I think maybe you can make it into a parallel circuit, but I'm not sure how. A diagram would be helpful.

Comment: yes, a schematic diagram would be useful ... you can add one to your question by using the button that looks like a schematic ... use the `save and insert` button to add the diagram to your post

Comment: I added the image, but I'm unsure how to proceed from solving there. I don't know how to convert it into a parallel circuit.

Comment: read your description of the circuit outloud ... does your picture show the same circuit?

Comment: Oh, there needs to be a 1 ohm resistor in the middle. But after that, I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: `there needs to be a 1 ohm resistor in the middle` ... why have you not changed the diagram? ... also add values and labels R1, R2 ...

Comment: If you draw it correctly, and assuming this is work for a class where they've already taught you about resistors in series and parallel, the problem becomes easy enough that you can do the calculations in your head. Look for ways to combine the resistances in series and parallel. [Edited by a moderator to comply with the Code of Conduct]

Comment: do you see any resistors that are connected in series?

Comment: Is there anything you can do to the resistors between A-B and B-C to simplify the circuit (same for A-D and D-C)?

Comment: @AldricBenalanA I am downvoting your question because the schematic diagram does not match the description of the circuit

Answer (score 0):

First you must draw in the resistor between A and C, because that's what you keep telling us. Then count the individual pathways between A and C. There are 3 pathways. Looking from the top they are 2 ohms, 1 ohm, and 2 ohms. You also know that multiple parallel pathways can be rearranged in order, as long as you don't change their endpoints. So the 3 paths in parallel, 2 and 1 and 2 ohms, can be written as 2 and 2 and 1 ohms. Now, you know that two 2-ohm resistors in parallel equals 1 ohm. That gives you a 1-ohm resistance in parallel with the final 1-ohm resistor. That equals ... ?